# PhantomJS console.log objects outputs [object object]

Tags: javascript, dom, phantomjs

I'm using the following code to get all img tags inside a page:

```
"use strict";
var system = require('system');
var args = system.args;
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.onLoadStarted = function () {
    console.log('Loading Page...');
};

page.onLoadFinished = function (status) {
  console.log('Loading finished.');
  var imgs = page.evaluate(function() {
    console.log(document.images);
    console.log(document.images.length);
    return document.images;
    });
  for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++){
    //console.log(JSON.stringify(imgs[i]));
    console.log(imgs[i]);
    console.log(imgs[i].alt);
    }
  phantom.exit();
};

page.open(system.args[1]);
```

It outputs the alt text correctly as expected, but on the line:

```
console.log(imgs[i]);
```

It only outputs: "[object object]" I would expect to get all of the img tag code, if i use JSON.stringify it outputs an immensely long msg that is also not the img tag code as I want.

Can anyone explain what is going on? How am I supossed to get the img tag code?

Comment: `console.log(imgs[i].outerHTML);`

Comment: @AndréDion that was it, thank you. Feel free to post it as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What's going on? Not sure to be honest. I suspect you're comparing PhantomJS's handling of logging an `Element` object with Chrome's JS Console which displays a live reference as the tag instead of `[Object object]`. If you were to `alert(imgs[i])` from Chrome you'd see `[Object HTMLImageElement]`.

You'll get what you want from `console.log(imgs[i].outerHTML);`.

See [`Element.outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML).